# Valid Series Convergence Proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences, divergent-series

Just wanted someone to check me to see if this is a valid proof. I've seen other proofs, but I can't use Cauchy condensation, or integral test as we haven't learned it yet. I have ratio test and comparison test at my disposal.

> Show how that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\log n}$ diverges.

---

$n>0$, so for all $n$, $0<(n \log n)^{-1}$. By $\Bbb Q$ dense in $\Bbb R$, for all $n$ there exists a $q$ such that

$$0<q<\frac1{n\log n}<\frac1{2\log2}$$

By the Archimedean property, there exits an $m$ such that $mq>(2\log2)^{-1}$. Therefore,

$$0<\frac1{2m\log2}<q<\frac1{n\log n}<\frac1{2\log2}$$

As $\sum 1/m$ diverges as it is the tail harmonic series, $1/(n\log n)$ diverges.

---

I'm a bit unsure of this, but I have no idea how else to show it using the tools I have.

Comment: Excellent attempt at MathJax $\ddot\smile$ Here’s te [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) for improvement

Answer (score 2):

Note that using the inequality $\log(x)\le x-1$ ([See This Answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263)), it is easy to show

$$\begin{align}
\log(\log(n+1))-\log(\log(n))&=\log\left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}\right)\\\\
&\le\frac{\log(n+1)-\log(n)}{\log(n)}\\\\
&\le \frac1{n\log(n)}\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Summing both sides of $(1)$ reveals

$$\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n\log(n)}\ge \log(\log(N+1))-\log(\log(2))\to \infty$$

as $N\to \infty$.  And we are done!

Comment: Okay, I see where you're going, but I don't see what you're summing over on the right hand side in the last equation. Shouldn't you have N terms? not just 2?

Comment: Nevermind, I see. Thank You so much

Comment: @Mercury You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @Mercury Feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

No, your proof is not correct. The reason is as follows: your argument amounts to

> for every $n$ there exists $m(n)$ such that 
>   $$
> \frac{1}{(2\log 2)m(n)} < \frac{1}{n\log n}
> $$
>   and *therefore* $\sum_{m=1}^N \frac{1}{(2\log 2)m} < \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n\log n}$; but the LHS diverges.

The "therefore" is where things go haywire. You are summing $\frac{1}{m(n)}$ for $n\geq 1$, **not** $\frac{1}{m}$ for $m\geq 1$. And nothing tells you that the series with partial sums $$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{m(n)}$$ diverges. (For instance, why couldn't it be for instance the case that $m(n) = 2^n$)?

---

Now, as you mention two usual ways to prove divergence of $\sum_n \frac{1}{n\log n}$ are either the [Cauchy condensation criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), or the comparison series-integral (noting that a primitive of $\frac{1}{x\log x}$ is $\log\log x$). You may not use them yet, but once you learn them I encourage you to try to apply them to this case. (The ratio test will not help you here, and neither the comparison test -- for instance, with $p$-series.)

Comment: Nice to see you've returned!  I've provided an elementary way forward that relies on telescoping and an elementary inequality only.

Comment: @MarkViola Is anyone ever truly gone? :) Saw your answer (and upvoted). If the OP has in their quiver the two arrows I've mentioned, then I believe them feels very natural (and allows to conclude almost immediately) -- not sure the OP knows them, however.

Comment: Indeed.  The OP mentioned that use of the integral test and Cauchy's Condensation test are prohibited.

Comment: @MarkViola Ah, indeed. Updated my answer -- though I'm leaving it, as it addresses the main question (correctness of the OP's proof).

Comment: (+1) for addressing and identifying the flaw in the OP's approach